# CSS Sliding doors trouble

Tags: html, css, phpbb

I'm having some minor issues with my CSS Sliding doors on my website. They appear fine on lower resolutions, but higher resolutions appear to make the button bigger and therefore causing the buttons :hover state to not work as it should.

You can see the problem in the right hand side of the header bar here (Login/Register Buttons):
http://www.bituser.com/forum/home.php

I have tried multiple solutions such as using different sizes for fonts and changing how the fonts are measured, but I get the feeling I am going about it the wrong way.

Here is a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bituser/vkMEg/1/ (It doesn't quite appear right on there, but you should see majority of the code used on the site).

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't load one of the images.

You have:

```
#user_buttons_right_header span {
    background: url("./styles/prosilver/theme/images/button_left.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding: 1px 10px 4px;
}
```

You should have

```
#user_buttons_right_header span {
    background: url("http://www.bituser.com/forum/styles/prosilver/theme/images/button_left.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    padding: 1px 10px 4px;
}
```

You forgot to make all of the background images have absolute path.

Except a font everything seems to be okay.

**EDIT:**

IMHO the problem may lie in line-height that should be set in pixels.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your reply. Please note that the absolute path was just an error when I was trying to adapt the HTML and CSS from the site to JSFiddle. I use Tahoma on the actual website, could that cause the problem?

Comment: You should specify line-height. Then text will render with specified height.